# Combining ArcTan's like in Maple

Tags: simplifying-expressions, trigonometry

It seems to me there is no simple way to combine ArcTan's with complex arguments symbolically in Mathematica as it is in Maple (https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=combine%2Farctan).

[image: implementation in Maple]

Please point me to the best way to achieve this.

Comment: You can just do things like (compare to your link), FullSimplify[{ArcTan[1/2 + I/2] + ArcTan[1 - I], 
  ArcTan[1/8] + ArcTan[1/7] + ArcTan[1/5] + ArcTan[1/3], 
  ArcTan[1/3] + ArcTan[1/4] , 
  3 ArcTan[1/3] - 2 ArcTan[1/4] + ArcTan[1/5]}]. Also, you can write that expression as a function too.

Comment: @Moo For constant values, it works fine. The problem is in the case of symbolic expressions

Comment: As I said, you can just write that piecewise function.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know why Mathematica can't simplify your expression.

A workaround might be

```
Tan[ArcTan[x] + ArcTan[y]] // TrigExpand // Simplify
(* (x + y)/(1 - x y) *)
```

which gives the result `ArcTan[x] + ArcTan[y]==n Pi+ArcTan[(x + y)/(1 - x y)]` 
Phase relationship `n Pi`has to be considered separately.

Comment: But this is not the correct answer in all cases

Comment: As I wrote at the end of my answer you have to consider the phase shift `n Pi`!